# Multi-armed bandit algorithms in Java?

Tags: java, multiarmed-bandit

Multi-armed_bandit problem defenition from Wikipeda:

"In probability theory, the multi-armed bandit problem (sometimes called the K-[1] or N-armed bandit problem) is the problem a gambler faces at a row of slot machines, sometimes known as "one-armed bandits", when deciding which machines to play, how many times to play each machine and in which order to play them. When played, each machine provides a random reward from a distribution specific to that machine. The objective of the gambler is to maximize the sum of rewards earned through a sequence of lever pulls" (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-armed_bandit)

In other words Multi-armed bandit (MAB) problems are a class of sequential resource allocation problems concerned with allocating one or more resources among several alternative (competing) projects / 'arms'. Such problems have a conﬂict between making decisions (allocating resources) that yield high current rewards, versus making decisions that sacriﬁce current gains with the prospect of better future rewards.

Any Java implementations for these algorithms?

Comment: Most certainly. What is your goal?

Comment: The goal is to learn MAB using Feynman's problem as a toy task: http://www.feynmanlectures.info/solutions/restaurant_problem_sol_1.html

Comment: If you want to learn, why not code it yourself?

Comment: Other people code helps me to understand how the algorithm works. Do you have any examples of MAB in Java or Python, maybe?

Comment: This is probably what you are looking for: http://mloss.org/software/view/415/

Comment: Welcome to the site, @BigG. This isn't really an answer to the OP's question. It is more of a comment. Please only use the "Your Answer" field to provide answers. I recognize it's frustrating, but you will be able to comment anywhere when your reputation >50. Alternatively, you could try to expand it to make it more of an answer. Since you are new here, you may want to read our [tour page](http://stats.stackexchange.com/about), which contains information for new users.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're only describing a problem. There are many different algorithms that can be applied to solve it, see e.g. http://lane.compbio.cmu.edu/courses/slides_ucb.pdf.

The UCB1 algorithm is so dead simple, reading Java code to understand how it works is probably a bad idea - unless you want to learn Java:

Play machine $j$, that maximizes

$$\bar{x}_j+\sqrt{\frac{2\ln n}{n_j}},$$
where $\bar{x}_j$ is the average reward obtained from machine $j$, $n_j$ is how often $j$ has been played and $n$ is the number of total plays.
The 2 in the formula is a constant which can be changed to tune the exploration vs exploitation of the algorithm (higher number results in more exploration).

Comment: By any chance might you have the pdf you are referring to and could share it?
The page doesn't seem to be working.
References to other material for beginners would also be welcomed. Thanks

Comment: found it https://web.archive.org/web/20140327071326/http://lane.compbio.cmu.edu/courses/slides_ucb.pdf